# C# Mongo Driver : "$project or $group does not support Sum([Cost])"

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to get a result using this query with Linq. I use Mongo Driver version 2.1.1 and I receive this error: "$project or $group does not support Sum([Cost])":

```
            lstSavings = (from data in collection.AsQueryable<SavingsDTOMongo>()
                          where data.ProjectId.Equals(projectId) &
                             //((projectConsumptionId != default(Guid)) ? data.ProjectConsumptionId == projectConsumptionId : true) &
                          plantIds.Contains(data.PlantId) &
                          data.DateTime >= startDate & data.DateTime <= endDate
                          group data by new { projectId = data.ProjectId, plantId = data.PlantId, cost = data.Cost } into groupedData
                          select new SavingsDTO
                          {
                              ProjectId = groupedData.Key.projectId,
                              PlantId = groupedData.Key.plantId,
                              BaselineConsumption = groupedData.Sum(x => x.BaselineConsumption),
                              BaselineCost = groupedData.Sum(x => x.BaselineCost),
                              Consumption = groupedData.Sum(x => x.Consumption),
                              Cost = groupedData.Sum (x => x.Cost)
                              ConsumptionSavings = groupedData.Sum(x => x.ConsumptionSavings),
                              CostSavings = groupedData.Sum(x => x.CostSavings)
                          }).ToList();
```

The driver doesn't allow me to select the total sum of different fields, as BaselineCost, consumption, ....
It only happens if I have the condition "plantIds.Contains(data.PlantId). If I delete this condition, it works.

I found a solution. Group data with Lambda Expression. But I would like to group data with LinQ because the aggregation operation is executed directly in mongoServer.

Somebody knows how to solve this driver bug to allows select with contains condition and sum(results) from grouped data?

Comment: Have you solved this?